¿Como instalar Rtools 4.4 para desarrollar mi programa en r studio?
Quiero instalar rtools 4.4 pero esta versión reciente no tiene una documentación para copiarla y pegarla en el gitbash al igual que la 4.0

¿Y cuál es el problema que tienes? ¿En SO estas trabajando? Si se trata de windows hay dsiponible un istalador: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools44/rtools.html
